# set UIImage on Detected Face using XHFaceMaskSDKSimple ,No able to add Images other then static added in demo

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, masking

I am using this [demo](https://github.com/Vanson/XHFaceMaskSDKSimple).

To put UIImage on recognized face where in this demo there is 3 static available images: **(hat,mustache,goggles)**

But I want to add my own images instead of mustache and other 2 like if i add phantom then it should show on face but i am not able to do it,i have checked throughout all files but i am not able to found it.

How  can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add your own custom UIImage, follow these two steps

1- you have to find `images.xcassets` in your project

[image]

2- In this folder you can add your own images by drag and drop in these boxes 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i know that but i am not able to add Images in project i mean in demo if instead of mustache i want to use phantom then how can i use it?

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**

1-In the project navigator, select an asset catalog.

2-Select an image in the Finder, and drag it to the set list in the selected asset catalog.

3-To add another image to the image set, drag the image from the Finder to the appropriate image well in the set viewer.

[Click here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEACL.png)

Comment: i know that but i am not able to add Images in project i mean in demo if instead of mustache i want to use phantom then how can i use it?